# PHP 7.0 / SOAP not closing connection with appropriate header

Tags: php, soap, php-7, soap-client, php-7.0

**Expected result:**

When receiving data from the SOAP server, the connection will terminate

**Actual result:**

When making SOAP calls the connection is left open all the way to `default_socket_timeout` max value before finally terminating. I've currently set it to 5 seconds just  to get reliable response times (which is still ridiculous)

**PHP 7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli)**

I'm sure a lot of this is redundant, but I just started throwing everything at the constructor just to see if something would stick.

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array('http' =>
        array(
            'protocol_version' => '1.1',
            'header'           => 'Connection: close'
        )
    )
);

$this->_soap_client = new SoapClient($host_uri . '/api/' . MagentoSoap::V1_SOAP . '/?wsdl', array(
    'cache_wsdl'     => WSDL_CACHE_DISK,
    'keep_alive'     => false,
    'stream_context' => $context,
    'trace'          => 1
));

//HANGS HERE (and subsequent soap calls to php.ini's default_socket_timeout value)
$this->_soap_session = $this->_soap_client->login($this->_config['magento_api_credentials']['username'], $this->_config['magento_api_credentials']['password']);
```

Example Request/Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 24 Aug 2018 15:53:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 544
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=db509bea5b6140817d0ab01daef54d6141535126021; expires=Sat, 24-Aug-19 15:53:41 GMT; path=/; domain=.xxx.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=62c4ff56a5ccc17b26700129a19636e1; expires=Wed, 24-Aug-2118 21:10:21 GMT; Max-Age=3155692600; path=/; domain=www.xxx.com; secure; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 44f6fe42ff88921e-EWR

POST /index.php/api/soap/index/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.xxx.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "urn:Action"
Content-Length: 642
Cookie: __cfduid=d8a5d51205add299655b6ab5478d3b8e41535126399;PHPSESSID=a201c37d45c983ee121c3f5a4716b29f;
```

php.ini's soap values:

```
root@middleware-production:~/middleware# php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep soap
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini,
soap
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400
```